# How to read the param value from the object tag using javascript

Tags: javascript, flash

Is it possible to read the playerID value using JavaScript?

```
<object id="myid" class="newclass">
  <param name="bgcolor" value="#FFFFFF" />
  <param name="width" value="345" />
  <param name="height" value="216" />
  <param name="playerID" value="1234" />
  <param name="playerKey" value="AFASS" />
  <param name="isVid" value="true" />
  <param name="isUI" value="true" />
</object>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Or, you can try the following statement. It will return all the play IDs on the page, if you have multiple.

```
var playerIDs = document.getElementsByName('playerID');
```

playerIDs will be an array. If you only have one playerID on the page, you can just say `playerIDs[0]`

Comment: When I alert playerIDs, I get object as response. when I alert playerIDs[0], I get undefined. I need the value for the playerID. unable to get it.

Comment: awesome, thanks for the demo. Let me figure out where I go wrong!

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
var obj = document.getElementById('myId');
var value = '';
for(var param in obj.childNodes){
   if (obj.childNodes[param].getAttribute('name') == 'playerID'){
      value = obj.childNodes[param].getAttribute('value');
      break;
   }
}
```